# Nginx прокси с контент фильтрацией

Tags: прокси, nginx

Всем привет ))). Начну с улыбки, так как голова 3-и сутки болит. Есть такая проблема. 3 сервака на всех nginx, первый принимает запросы от пользователей и перенаправляет их upstream на 2 других. Те двое обрабатывают запросы (лезут дальше в инет) и выполняют контент фильтрацию модулем naxsi и передают первому, тот возвращает пользователюnginx,conf -первого

```
#user  nobody;worker_processes  1;worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;#pid        logs/nginx.pid;events {    worker_connections  5000;    use epoll;}http {    include       mime.types;     default_type  application/octet-stream;    sendfile        on;    tcp_nopush  on;    tcp_nodelay on;        keepalive_timeout  65;        resolver 8.8.8.8;upstream  blabla.net {        server 172.16.168.2:80;        server 172.16.168.3:80;}upstream www.blabla.net {        server 172.16.168.2:80;        server 172.16.168.3:80;} server {        listen      ip:80;         server_name  blabla.net;         location / {        proxy_pass  $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args;                        }        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;        location = /50x.html {            root   html;                           }               }}
```

Настройка 2-ого и 3-ого идентичная -

```
#user  nobody;worker_processes 1;worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;#pid        logs/nginx.pid;events {    worker_connections  2048;use epoll;}http {    include       mime.types;    default_type  application/octet-stream;    sendfile        on;    tcp_nopush     on;    #keepalive_timeout  0;    keepalive_timeout  65;        tcp_nodelay on;    #gzip  on;  resolver 8.8.8.8;    include /etc/nginx/conf/naxsi_core.rules;    server {        listen       172.16.168.2:80; server_name  localhost;        access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access.log;        location / {                proxy_pass $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args;                #NAXSI CONF                SecRulesEnabled;                DeniedUrl "/403";                CheckRule "$ODNO >= 4" BLOCK;                BasicRule wl:2;                if ($arg_cmd = getLiveSearch) {                        return 403;                                                }                }        location /uploadImage {                proxy_pass $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args;                                }        location /403 {                return 403;                        }         }}
```

Вот эти настройки, проблема в логах errora следующая

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client:ip

Я не могу понять, в чем может быть дело!! Правила все отрабатывают, контент фильтрация работает, прокси работает, но ошибок очень много и они не прекращаются, кто может что подсказать - заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Наверное таймауты маленькие, ответы не вписываются во время отведенное для задержки.

```
keepalive_timeout  65;
```

Comment: Менял на 120, ни к чему не привело.

Comment: Посмотреть в логах куда отсылается пакет, возможно в никуда, и возвращается ли пакет из интернета на шлюз, если на один и тот же адрес пакеты то ходят то нет, однозначно проблема в тайм-аутах,